# MATLAB flip definition of angles (or alternative angular metric)

Tags: matlab, angle

I am doing work on symmetric images where I would like to define a symmetric (polar) coordinate space. Basically for the left image, I want 0 degrees to be defined along the right horizontal axis (as is the default). However, for the right image, I want 0 degrees to be defined along the left horizontal axis.

I know a phase shift of pi would do the trick. However, for comparison purposes, I am trying to keep the range of angles the same, [-pi : pi).

[image]

In the above color plot of the rotations in an object, note that they are both defined in the same direction. Ideally I'd like to see the colors of the right object flipped across its vertical axis.

I should note that these angles are calculated by taking the arctan(y/x) of the perimeter coordinates when measured from the centroid. Is there a different trig function that may result in the proper symmetry? I couldn't seem to come up with one while still claiming it was representative of direction.

Comment: So you want to be able to say `x1 = foo(t1); x2 = foo(t2); [x1 + x2 == 0, t1 - t2 == 0]` gives `[1,1]`?

Comment: Where foo() is a trigonometric function I presume? The t1-t2 part is right, but I'm not quite sold on the x1+x2 piece though. I think x1+x2 = pi is actually correct.

Comment: Doing a flip across the vertical axis would preserve angles, would that be adequate? (I don't really understand the question)

Comment: How do you draw this, can you add some code? Could be an image or two plots combined with subplot.

Comment: Flipping data by pi is hardly a big deal.  Why are you concerned with "comparison" of numeric data vs.  drawing the graph the way you want?  Just take your data `x`  and do `plot(-x)`  or `plot(x-pi)`  .

Comment: You may want to read about the moebius transform, if you like to solve stuff with maths.